# elasticsearch agregate by max, into buckets by field and sort by another

Tags: elasticsearch

I have docs with structure:

`{group: 1, year: 2013, profit: 150}
{group: 1, year: 2014, profit: 100}
{group: 2, year: 2014, profit: 80}
{group: 2, year: 2015, profit: 180}`

I need to find highest year for every group and than results sort by profit. So I am expecting result like:

`{group: 2, year: 2015, profit: 180}
{group: 1, year: 2014, profit: 150}`

I found how to create aggregation inside another, get data by top_hits but can not get know, how to sort by profit at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [sort by a metric](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting_by_a_metric.html) to sort inner aggregations.

example:

```
GET /cars/transactions/_search
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "colors" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "color",
              "order": {
                "avg_price" : "asc" 
              }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "avg_price": {
                    "avg": {"field": "price"} 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query:

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
"size": 0, 
"aggs": {
  "aggregate_by_group": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "group",
          "order": {
           "max_profit": "desc"
        }
     },
     "aggs": {
        "max_profit": {
           "max": {
              "field": "profit"
           }
        },
          "top_category_hits": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "sort": [
                        {
                            "year": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "size" : 1
                }
            }
     }

   }
  }
}
```

Output will be:

```
 "aggregations": {
  "aggregate_by_group": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": 2,
           "doc_count": 2,
           "top_category_hits": {
              "hits": {
                 "total": 2,
                 "max_score": null,
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_index": "so1",
                       "_type": "so1",
                       "_id": "4",
                       "_score": null,
                       "_source": {
                          "group": 2,
                          "year": 2015,
                          "profit": 180
                       },
                       "sort": [
                          2015
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
           },
           "max_profit": {
              "value": 180
           }
        },
        {
           "key": 1,
           "doc_count": 2,
           "top_category_hits": {
              "hits": {
                 "total": 2,
                 "max_score": null,
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_index": "so1",
                       "_type": "so1",
                       "_id": "2",
                       "_score": null,
                       "_source": {
                          "group": 1,
                          "year": 2014,
                          "profit": 100
                       },
                       "sort": [
                          2014
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
           },
           "max_profit": {
              "value": 150
           }
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

You can see here the result is sorted by profit.
You will fetch the desired values like highest year from `sort` value and profit from `max_profit` aggregation not from `_source`.

Comment: but this do not filter results by latest year for every group - I need firstly found latest year for every group and than sort on this latest docs profit

Comment: @japlavaren, I have edited the query according to your requirement.Please verify again.